# transform int values to color objects using XSL and Java

Tags: java, xslt

I am new in XSL and I have an xml file with tags representing int rgb colors,
I want using XSL to convert them into Color object tags:

my xml contains these tags

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
.
.
.
<ForeGroundColour>-16776961</ForeGroundColour>
.
.
.
</xml>
```

the desired xml is:

```
<ForeGroundColour>
  <red>102</red>
  <blue>102</blue>
  <green>255</green>
  <alpha>255</alpha>
</ForeGroundColour>
```

my XSL file is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:Color="java.awt.Color"
    xmlns:Integer="java.lang.Integer" exclude-result-prefixes="Color Integer ">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<!-- identity template !-->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="//*[contains(name(),'ForegroundColour')]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="rgb" select="." />
            <xsl:variable name="color" select="Color:new(Integer:parseInt($rgb))" />
            <xsl:element name="red">
                <xsl:value-of select="Color:getRed($color)" />
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="blue">
                <xsl:value-of select="Color:getBlue($color)" />
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="green">
                <xsl:value-of select="Color:getGreen($color)" />
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="alpha">
                <xsl:value-of select="Color:getAlpha($color)" />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have two problems:

1- when I run this code, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: (class: transformer, method: template$dot$1 signature: (Lcom/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/xsltc/DOM;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/dtm/DTMAxisIterator;Lcom/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/serializer/SerializationHandler;I)V) Expecting to find double on stack
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TemplatesImpl.getTransletInstance(TemplatesImpl.java:364)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TemplatesImpl.newTransformer(TemplatesImpl.java:394)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:649)
    at com.nyfix.ostp.server.workspacemigrator.XMLTransformer.transform(XMLTransformer.java:44)
    at com.nyfix.ostp.server.workspacemigrator.XSLMigrator.migrate(XSLMigrator.java:45)
    at com.nyfix.ostp.server.workspacemigrator.WorkspaceMigratorFactory.<init>(WorkspaceMigratorFactory.java:19)
    at com.nyfix.ostp.server.workspacemigrator.WorkspaceMigratorFactory.main(WorkspaceMigratorFactory.java:45)
```

2- when I use the template just to test the inserted nodes,

```
<xsl:template match="//*[contains(name(),'ForegroundColour')]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="rgb" select="." />
        <xsl:element name="red">
            <xsl:value-of select="$rgb" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="blue">
            <xsl:value-of select="$rgb" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="green">
            <xsl:value-of select="$rgb" />
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="alpha">
            <xsl:value-of select="$rgb" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

the xml is transformed without indentation:

```
                      <ForegroundColour>
<red>-16776961</red>
<blue>-16776961</blue>
<green>-16776961</green>
<alpha>-16776961</alpha>
</ForegroundColour>
```

can anyone help me with this? thanks in advance

Comment: Most probably you don't need extension functions at all. Please, *edit* the question and describe the algorithm to produce RGB from an integer -- then probably many readers would offer a pure XSLT solution.

Comment: to produce java Color object from an integer value, we just need to call new Color(integer) which is described in the XSL by            <xsl:variable name="color" select="Color:new(Integer:parseInt($rgb))" />

Comment: bolbol, What I am asking is the *algorithm* that this extension function uses -- this can be implemented directly in XSLT -- no extension functions are needed in most such cases.

Comment: thank you dimitre for you response, I was waiting for one all the day :) as I told you in the last comment, I'm using standard JAVA API to get the color, so basically, I get the rgb int color from the node and then convert it to java object using  new Color(integer) and then I get the red value by calling color.getRGB(),

Comment: bolbol, correct `<xsl:variable name="rgb" select="." />` to `<xsl:variable name="rgb" select="string(.)" />` and try it.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT variables can contain only strings, booleans, numbers or node-sets - the `Color:new(...)` call returns a Java object, that cannot be assigned to an XSLT variable, hence the exception.

Possible solutions:

1) Create your own extension class with methods `stringToRed`, `stringToBlue` etc defined so that they accept a string, convert it internally to the `Color` object and then extract the wanted component (Red, Blue etc) as a number or string . These functions then can be used directly:

```
<xsl:element name="red">
  <xsl:value-of select="MyColorFunctions:stringToRed(.)" />
</xsl:element>
```

2) 'Reverse-engineer' the algorithm that converts a color expressed as an integer to its component, and implement it directly in XSLT, without using extension function. Typically the red component will be the 8 least significative bits, the blu the next 8 bits and so on (or vice-versa), and you have to handle the negative values (convert from 2-complement to absolute) - so something like this:

```
  <xsl:variable name="color">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="number(.) &gt;=0">
        <xsl:value-of select="number(.)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="4278190080+number(.)"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <red>
    <xsl:value-of select="floor($color mod 256)" />
  </red>
  <green>
    <xsl:value-of select="floor(($color div 256) mod 256)" />
  </green>
  <blue>
    <xsl:value-of select="floor(($color div 65536) mod 256)" />
  </blue>
  <alpha>
    <xsl:value-of select="floor(($color div 16777216) mod 256)" />
  </alpha>
```

The problem with this apprach is that XSLT use floating point arithmentic, so it is possible that rounding errors cause wrong values for the components in some cases.

Comment: thanks Mimo for your response, I used the first approach to resolve the problem, however for the indentation, I am using the <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> in my xsl file, the problem is that the tags already existing in the document are indented, but the node and the ones I insert into it are not

Comment: @bolbol: you're welcome. Concerning the indentation: the `indent="yes"` directive applies to everything that is generated by the XSLT - but it works only if the output of the XSLT is a string or a file, if the output is a XML DOM object it will be ignored - maybe this is your problem?

Comment: I think this is exactly my problem, have you any clue how to fix it?

Comment: @bolbol: there should be some options to generate the indentation when you write the XML DOM object to a file - I am not familiar with the Java XML libraries, so I cannot tell you the exact code to use

Answer (score 0):

it's a little bit late to answer the question, but it's for anyone who can have the same problem,

for the indenation issue, I had to use custom xsl templates to make sure the output xml is indentend in the way I want.

the template includes many dirty code that forces xml tags to have special spacing that simulates the indentation

hope this help :)